# "Use of unassigned variable" in my first C# script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, variables

I know many people did threads to this but I didn't find anything particularly useful..

I am very new to Unity and C# and I'm having a very common error called "use of unassigned variable".

This is some of my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

int testvar = 0;

public class test : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (testvar < 10)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("the variable is below 10");
            testvar += 1;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("your variable is over 10:");
            Console.WriteLine(testvar);
        }
    }
}
```

I get the issue with the variable `testvar`.

I didn't change any other aspects of the unity 3d project base.
Can somebody please tell me what's wrong with the script?

I thought to have a simple program with the outputs:

```
your variable is below 10
your variable is below 10
your variable is below 10
your variable is below 10
your variable is below 10
your variable is below 10
your variable is below 10
your variable is below 10
your variable is below 10
your variable is below 10
your variable is above 10:
10
your variable is above 10:
11
your variable is above 10:
12
your variable is above 10:
13
......
..........
.............
```

Comment: Try moving `int testvar = 0;` inside the class.

Answer (score 3):

Declare `testvar` inside your class :

```
public class test : MonoBehaviour
{
     int testvar = 0;
     
     ... rest of code
}
```